# Using with generic methods in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, generics, razor, using

Is there a way to make the `using` statement work with generic methods in razor views? For example I'd like the webforms snippet

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm<Controller>(c => c.Method()))
   { %>
       Some code
<% } %>
```

converted to razor like this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm<Controller>(c => c.Method()))
{
    Some code
}
```

but that does not work, since razor interprets `<Controller>` as an HTML tag. Adding parentheses does not work either, since then razor does not include the curly brackets that begin and end the `BeginForm`. Below are the different approaches I've tried, and I can't think of any more.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm<Controller>(c => c.Method())) // Interpreted as c# to '<Controller>'
{                                                   // interpreted as HTML
    Some code                                       // interpreted as HTML
}                                                   // interpreted as HTML

@(using(Html.BeginForm<Controller>(c => c.Method()))) // Interpreted as c#
{                                                     // interpreted as HTML
    Some code                                         // interpreted as HTML
}                                                     // interpreted as HTML

@{using(Html.BeginForm<Controller>(c => c.Method())) // Interpreted as c#
    {                                                // interpreted as c#
        Some code                                    // interpreted as c#
    }                                                // interpreted as c#
}                                                    // interpreted as c#

@(using(Html.BeginForm<Controller>(c => c.Method()))) // Interpreted as c#
@{                                                    // interpreted as c#
        Some code                                     // interpreted as c#
}                                                     // interpreted as c#
```

Does aynone know how to do this?

**Update**: It seems the third way above is the way to do this. Razor apparently works like this:

```
@{using(Html.BeginForm<Controller>(c => c.Method())) // Interpreted as c#
    {                                                // interpreted as c#
        <p>                                          // interpreted as HTML
        Some text                                    // interpreted as HTML
        @Code                                        // interpreted as c#
        </p>                                         // interpreted as HTML
    }                                                // interpreted as c#
}                                                    // interpreted as c#
```

Not the most obvious way of doing things, but it works.

**Update 2**: Razor has probably been updated at some point, because now option #1 above works as expected.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm<Controller>(c => c.Method()))
{
    Some code
}
```

Comment: It appears to work just fine on my end. But there's no `BeginForm<T>` available (i made a quick helper method to test) so are you using an external library or something? What's the error in the Razor Syntax?

Comment: We're using the MvcContrib extensions from Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll, which contains a number of strongly typed html helpers. The error is that @(Html.BeginForm<T>(...)) works fine but @using(Html.BeginForm<T>(...)) does not and I can't figure out a way to format it so that it would work.

Answer (score 8):

What if you wrap the whole statement in parens:

```
@(using(Html.BeginForm<Controller>(c => c.Method())))
```

Or use a code block?

HTH.

Comment: I've tried that and it's no good. Added examples of different attempts above.

Comment: Works for me in MVC 4.5.